# Add new item in ListView then update to database

Tags: c#, listview

Here is my code for adding item in the `ListView` then add to database.

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string cd = "Update ProductSold set [BillNo] = '" + txtBillNoE.Text + "',[DishName] = @d2, [DishRate] = @d3 , [Quantity] = @d4 , [TotalAmount] = @d5 where BillNo = " + txtBillNoE.Text + "";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I'll give you a scenario in my program to make the problem clear, I have already two items in my `ListView` and I have an update button. When I clicked the update button I want to add a new item then add to database but when I get the data its the new add item and its doubled but the 2 old items gone.

Comment: Yes, because you are overwriting the values with next update.

Comment: How to solve that sir?

Comment: If you want to keep the old values, then use Insert instead of Update.

Comment: how? the code above is the code for inserting.

Comment: @JohnKennethdeLara No its for updating..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as following;

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string cd = @"INSERT INTO ProductSold (BillNo, DishName, DishRate, Quantity, TotalAmount)
                  VALUES (@BillNo, @DishName, @DishRate, @Quantity, @TotalAmount)";

    cmd = new OleDbCommand(cd);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillNo", txtBillNoE.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DishName", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DishRate", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount", ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i try this but yes the older items remains but its doubled with the new updated item.

Comment: I already solved it myself you gave me a clue sir, thanks! :)